# Prove $\left[F:\operatorname{Fix}(G)\right] \geq |G|$ if $G$ is finite and acts faithfully on $F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

I am looking at the last paragraph of [this](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/09I3) lemma. Basically given a finite group $G$ acting faithfully on the field $F$, it claimed that $\left[F:\operatorname{Fix}(G)\right] \geq |G|$, or using primitive element theorem, $$[\operatorname{Fix}(G)[\alpha]:\operatorname{Fix}(G)]\geq|G|.$$

Equivalently, the degree of the minimal polynomial $p_\alpha\in \operatorname{Fix}(G)[x]$ cannot be smaller than $|G|$. I understand $p_\alpha$ is a factor of the polynomial $$P=\prod_{\beta\in \alpha\cdot G}(x-\beta)\in\operatorname{Fix}(G)[x]$$ but how does the faithfulness imply $P$ is irreducible?

Comment: My problem is solved. The author assumes the group $G$ acting faithfully by field isomorphisms $\operatorname{Fix}(G)[\alpha]\to \operatorname{Fix}(G)[\alpha]$. See the paragraph before the lemma(link provided in the question.)